# Problema al mostrar un contenido dependiente de un SELECT en Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Tengo unas tabla llamadas **'AUTOS'** y **'COMPAÑIAS'**, respectivamente, en mi base de datos en *phpmyadmin.* Estoy trabajando en **PHP** con **LARAVEL.**

Tengo una funcion en **Javascript** la cual me debe mostrar una determinada cantidad de registros según la opción seleccionada de un `<select>`.

De momento lo que trato de lograr es que, cuando se seleccione una opción del select, se muestren unos checkbox que le corresponden a la opción seleccionada respectivamente.

Por ejemplo si se selecciona la compañía de id = 1 la cual es Mazda, los checkbox que deben mostrase corresponden únicamente a modelos de esta marca.

El `<select>` obtiene los datos de la tabla compañia de mi base de datos, mediante código php. Igual como este ejemplo.

```
<select name="SelectCompañias" onchange="MostrarAutos()">
  @foreach($compañia as $concesionario)
  <option value="{{$concesionario->id}}">{{$concesionario->nombre}}</option>
  @endif    
</select>
```

Pero de momento no me funciona el *js* solo me trae el 1 registro nada más.

El cual es el siguiente:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function MostrarAutos(){
    var DiVAutos = document.getElementById('AutosDiv');
    var Lista = document.autos.SelectAutos.value;

    if (Lista.value == {{$autos->compañia_id}}) {

        DiVAutos.style.display = "inline-block ";


    }else if (Lista.value == ''){
        DiVAutos.style.display = "none";
    }

  }
</script>
```

Siendo este el Div con los checkbox que quiero mostrar.

```
@foreach($autos as $autos)
   <div id="DiVAutos">                            
     <input type="checkbox" id="{{$autos->nombre}}" value="{{$autos->id}}" name="autos[]">

     <label id="LabelAutos" style="color: grey;" for="{{$autos->nombre}}">{{$autos->nombre}}</label>
     <br>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Lo siguiente es un ejemplo de lo que quiero lograr. Es completamente diferente en cuanto al contenido, pero en el aspecto funcional es lo mismo.

> **Nota:** Aclaro que lo siguiente es solo un ejemplo, y no lo que en verdad tengo en mi código.

```js
function MostrarAutos(){
      
    var Autos_1 = document.getElementById('Conjunto_autos_1');
    var Autos_2 = document.getElementById('Conjunto_autos_2'); 
    var Autos_3 = document.getElementById('Conjunto_autos_3');
    var Autos_4 = document.getElementById('Conjunto_autos_4');
    var DiVLabelAutos = document.getElementById('AutosDiv');
    var boton = document.getElementById('btn_enviar');

       
      if(document.autos.SelectAutos.value == 'Mazda'){
        
         DiVLabelAutos.style.display = 'inline-block';
         Autos_1.style.display = 'inline-block';
         boton.style.display = 'inline-block';
         Autos_2.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_3.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_4.style.display = 'none';
            
      }else if(document.autos.SelectAutos.value == 'Nissan'){
          
         DiVLabelAutos.style.display = 'inline-block';
         Autos_2.style.display = 'inline-block';
         Autos_1.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_3.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_4.style.display = 'none';
         boton.style.display = 'inline-block';
  
            
      }else if(document.autos.SelectAutos.value == 'Chevrolet'){
          
         DiVLabelAutos.style.display = 'inline-block';
         Autos_3.style.display = 'inline-block';

         Autos_1.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_2.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_4.style.display = 'none';
         boton.style.display = 'inline-block';
            
            
      }else if(document.autos.SelectAutos.value == 'FIAT'){
          
         DiVLabelAutos.style.display = 'inline-block';
         Autos_4.style.display = 'inline-block';

         Autos_1.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_2.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_3.style.display = 'none';
         boton.style.display = 'inline-block';

            
       }else if(document.autos.SelectAutos.value == ''){
          
         DiVLabelAutos.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_1.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_2.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_3.style.display = 'none';
         Autos_4.style.display = 'none';
         boton.style.display = 'none';
            
      }
   }
```

```css
#autos{
        font-family: 'Segoe UI';
      }
      #cuerpo{
       font-family: 'Segoe UI';
       margin-left: 1cm;
      }  

      #btn_enviar{
        width: 12%;
      }
```

```html
<div id="cuerpo">
  <form action="#" method="POST" name="autos">
  <label>Seleccione una marca de Autos:</label>&nbsp;
  <select id="compañia" name="SelectAutos" onchange="MostrarAutos()">
     <option value="">Seleccione...</option>

     <option value="Mazda">Mazda</option>     
     <option value="Nissan">Nissan</option>
     <option value="Chevrolet">Chevrolet</option>
     <option value="FIAT">FIAT</option>
   </select>
   
        
        <br><br>
        <div>
        
        <div id="AutosDiv" style="display: none;">
          <label>Selecciona todos los autos</label>
          <br><br><br>
        </div>
        <br>
          <div id="Conjunto_autos_1" style="display: none;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="Mazda2" id="id_1" required="required"/>
            <label>Mazda2</label>
        
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="Mazda3" id="id_2" required="required"/>
            <label>Mazda3</label>
            <br>
          
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="Mazda MX-5" id="id_3" required="required"/>
            <label>Mazda MX-5</label>
          </div>
         
          <div id="Conjunto_autos_2" style="display: none;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="Nissan Juke" id="id_4" required="required"/>
            <label>Nissan Juke</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="Nissan GT-R">
            <label>Nissan GT-R</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="Nissan 370z">
            <label>Nissan 370z</label>
          </div>
          
          <div id="Conjunto_autos_3" style="display: none;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="Chevrolet Spark" id="id_5" required="required"/>
            <label>Chevrolet Spark</label>
            <br>
          
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="Chevrolet Aveo" id="id_6" required="required"/>
            <label>Chevrolet Aveo</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="Chevrolet Corvette >ZR1">
            <label>Chevrolet Corvette ZR1</label>
          </div>
            
          <div id="Conjunto_autos_4" style="display: none;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="FIAT 500" id="id_7" required="required"/>
            <label>FIAT 500</label>
            <br>
          
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="FIAT 124 Spider" id="id_8" required="required"/>
            <label>FIAT 124 Spider</label>
            <br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cuadro" value="FIAT 500L">
            <label>FIAT 500L</label>
          </div>
          
        <br><br>
        
        <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" id="btn_enviar" style="display: none;">
      
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Para explicar la relación entre **`compañia-autos`** la cual es **`1:M`** tengo estas tablas.

**`TABLA COMPAÑIA`**

```
id|nombre
------------
 1|Mazda
 2|Nissan
 3|Chevrolet
 4|FIAT
```

**`TABLA AUTOS`**

```
 id|nombre                 |compañia_id
---------------------------------------
 1 |Mazda2                 |        1
 2 |Mazda3                 |        1
 3 |Mazda MX-5             |        1
 4 |Nissan Juke            |        2
 5 |Nissan GT-R            |        2
 6 |Nissan 370z            |        2
 7 |Chevrolet Spark        |        3
 8 |Chevrolet Aveo         |        3
 9 |Chevrolet Corvette ZR1 |        3
 9 |FIAT 500               |        4
 10|FIAT 124 Spider        |        4
 11|FIAT 500L              |        4
```

Si se selecciona una compañía y esta es Mazda por ejemplo, los checkbox que deben mostrarse, corresponden a esta compañía igual que en el ejemplo.

Pero con el codigo que tengo en mi función en javascript no me funciona **(no en el ejemplo).** También podría ser con jquery.

¿Que podría estar mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En resumen he cambiado algunas cosillas.

```
<select name="SelectCompañias" onchange="MostrarAutos(event)">
  @foreach($compañia as $concesionario)
  <option value="{{$concesionario->id}}">{{$concesionario->nombre}}</option>
  @endif    
</select>

@foreach($autos as $autos)
    <div class="DiVAutos" style="display: none">  
         <input type="checkbox" data-concesionario="{{$autos->compañia_id}}" id="{{$autos->nombre}}" value="{{$autos->id}}" name="autos[]">
         <label id="LabelAutos" style="color: grey;" for="{{$autos->nombre}}">{{$autos->nombre}}</label>
         <br>
     </div>
@endforeach
```

Y el script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MostrarAutos(event){
        var target = $(event.target);
        var value = target.val();

        $('.DiVAutos').hide();
        $('[data-concesionario="'+value+'"]').closest('.DiVAutos').show();

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Probe aquello y no me funciona. ¿Porqué será?

Comment: te arroja algo la consola?  algun error de javascript?

Comment: no ningún error.

Comment: Mira el codigo fuente, y comprueba que <input type="checkbox" data-concesionario> esta siendo rellenado por algun numero

Comment: Gracias amigo, en un principio no lei bien tu respuesta. Me falto agregar esta linea al input. `data-concesionario="{{$autos->compañia_id}}" `. Y ahora funciona.

Comment: Ueeeee.!!! me alegro.